# How to make this look human

Tags: modeling

This is my second try to model a character this time I set the goal , that the model looks similar to me.

I have put really much effort in this, but I'm not happy with the result. It doens't look human.

What is the cause? How can I better imitate a human? How can I make it look like me? Which parts of the face should I rework? Is the texturing right?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Blender StackExchange isn't a site for critiques. I'd recommend checking out [Blender Artists](https://blenderartists.org) to get more helpful feedback.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for opinion based art critique, not a specific question about Blender

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this is mostly an opinion based question, you may want to ask this over at [Blender Artists](https://blenderartists.org) or similar communities instead

Answer (score 2):

It's not too bad. I couldn't say about the texture because your picture is too dark. But about the proportions I would say:

- Lengthen the forehead
- Shorten the chin
- Scale down and spread the ears
- Scale down and rise the nose up
- Scale up the mouth and thicken the lower lip
- Make the neck straight
- ...

To compare you could overlay your photo with your mesh, either in Blender or Photoshop.

[image]